# Can I set my autolayout constraints so that an imageview is set to the height of the image

Tags: ios, uitableview, uiimageview, autolayout

I am building out a dynamic tableview cell.  The height is dynamic based on the content that is loaded.  I'm running into a hangup with height of the imageview.  The images currently load aspect fill in an imageview that is 100% of the width.  Is it possible to set an autolayout constraint on my imageview so that the imageview is hidden (has a height of 0) if there is no image for a tableview cell?

[image]

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    TableViewTileCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"tileCell"];

    if (!cell)
    {
        [tableView registerNib:[UINib nibWithNibName:@"TableViewTileCell" bundle:nil] forCellReuseIdentifier:@"tileCell"];
        cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"tileCell"];
    }
    cell.tileView.layer.borderColor = [UIColor blackColor].CGColor;
    cell.tileView.layer.borderWidth = 1.0f;

    [cell.contentView setBackgroundColor:[UIColor colorWithRed:0.96 green:0.96 blue:0.96 alpha:1.0]];

    NSString *url=[self.resultsArray[indexPath.row] valueForKey:@"imageURL"];

    cell.tileTitle.text = [self.resultsArray[indexPath.row] valueForKey:@"title"];
    cell.tileDate.text = [self.resultsArray[indexPath.row] valueForKey:@"date"];
    cell.tileContent.text = [self.resultsArray[indexPath.row] valueForKey:@"summary"];

    if(![url isEqualToString:@""]){ //If we got a url value back load the image
        [cell.tileImageview setImageWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:url] placeholderImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"placeholder.png"]];
    }

    return cell;
}
```

Comment: Can you post your `cellForRowAtIndexPath`?

Answer (score 1):

> Is it possible to set an autolayout constraint on my imageview so that the imageview is hidden (has a height of 0) if there is no image for a tableview cell?

Make the whole cell content a vertical UIStackView. In `cellForRow`, make the image view hidden. The stack view has the wonderful ability to change the constraints in exactly the way you describe: when the image view is hidden, the constraints will change and the image view will occupy zero space, with the other views occupying the whole space.

The alternative is not terrible: you simply have to do, yourself, what the UIStackView would do — remove the empty image view in code and adjust the constraints, in `cellForRow`. Swapping constraints and views together into and out of the interface is standard practice, and is easy to do.

Comment: Thanks Matt! I had started down the process of cobbling together code to change the constraints conditionally but started to get the feeling it should be easier with autolayout.